Integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^\alpha)dx = \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^R \sin(x^\alpha)dx, \alpha>0$
For what values of $\alpha$ does the above improper integral exist? Justify the answer.
My attempt: By observation, I think apply the Residue Theorem is a common method to solve for the improper integral problem, hence I first let $f(z) = \sin(z^{\alpha})$, but I dont think it has a singularity. And if we dont use the Residue Theorem, the integral cannot be integrand directly.
Thank you so much for your help!

Intuitively, this can be thought of as the limit of an alternating sum, where we break the integral into intervals where the function is positive and negative. When $\alpha<1,$ those intervals get bigger and bigger, so the sum can't converge, But when $\alpha>1,$ those inters get smaller and smaller, approaching zero, and the sum becomes an alternating decreasing sum. But proving they are decreasing across the positive and negative intervals is decreasing is the hard part - visually, it makes sense to me, but I can't prove it.

It seems like if you change the variables using $x=u^{1/\alpha}$ you can prove and define: $$a_n=\int_{\pi n}^{\pi(n+1)} u^{1/\alpha-1}\sin u,du,$$ it is pretty east yo see this cannot converge when $\alpha\leq1$ since the values do not converge to zero, and if $\alpha>1$ the sequence alternates and $|a_n|$ decreases and converges to $0,$ so the integral converges then.

This would work for any  integrable function which is positive on $(0,L)$ and satisfies $f(x+L)=-f(x)$ for all $x\geq 0.$

Consider $\int\limits_1^\infty {\sin x\over x^{\alpha-1}}x^{\alpha-1},dx$ and apply the Dirichlet integral test with $g(x)=x^{\alpha-1}$ and $f(x)= {\sin x\over x^{\alpha-1}}.$ You will need $\alpha>1.$

@ThomasAndrews Hi Thomas, Thank you so much for your explaination, but I am still confused about how you get the domain of u, $[\pi n, \pi (n+1)]$, while I think the domain of x is $[0,n]$ and hence $u\in [0,n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}]$

Who said $[\pi n,\pi(n+1)]$ was the whole domain?  @xxxx666
